# How to configure Mongodb-Atlas in flask using flask_mongoalchemy?

Tags: mongodb, flask, mongodb-atlas, flask-mongoengine

I did put password of that user in the field and i have tried all possible combination with dbname.I dont know which dbname it is referring to. I have searched many places, didnt get any answers. Can some one please help me how to configure.

```
app.config['DEBUG']=True
app.config['MONGOALCHEMY_CONNECTION_STRING']='mongodb+srv://user: 
<password>@test.usvae.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
db=MongoAlchemy(app)
```

This is my configeration.
This is the error i am getting

raise ImproperlyConfiguredError("You should provide a database name "
flask_mongoalchemy.ImproperlyConfiguredError: You should provide a database name (the MONGOALCHEMY_DATABASE setting)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pymongo

## DB Connection ##  
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://mongouser:password@<cluster>/<db>?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
## DB Creation ##
db = client.<db>

## Collection Creation ##
col1 = db.Users

if client:
    print("connected")
else: 
    print("not connected")

# Single Value Insert ##
Users = {"ID":"481292","Name":"DS"}
#x1 = col1.insert_one(Users)
```

You can try above code to connect mongodb atlas to flask.

Below code for using mongodb atlas with flask_mongoalchemy

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mongoalchemy import MongoAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
DB_URI = 'mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@<cluster>/<db>?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
app.config['MONGOALCHEMY_DATABASE'] = 'test'
app.config["MONGODB_HOST"] = DB_URI


db = MongoAlchemy(app)

class Users(db.document):
    name = db.StringField()
    age = db.IntField()
```

You need to insert value as well, to avoid error.